# How do I set a system property for my project in sbt?

Tags: scala, project, sbt, system-properties

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple... I want to set the system property `java.awt.headless` to `true` for my sbt project. Reading the [page on properties](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Properties) I think that I need to use `system` or `systemOptional`. In my project file I've tried things like:

```
lazy val javaAwtHeadless = system[Boolean]("java.awt.headless")
```

Setting it as a user property (e.g. `lazy val javaAwtHeadless = property[Boolean]`) and setting the accompanying value in `build.properties` made the property visible in the sbt console but not within sbt's Scala console (via `System.getProperty("java.awt.headless")`).

`set java.awt.headless true` from the sbt console works, including being set in the Scala console, but it doesn't persist to the next time I launch sbt.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A straightforward method would be to edit the batch file or shell script that you use to run `sbt` and add `-Dprop=val`

Comment: Yes, but this would require me to change my sbt launch commands on all the machines I develop on, plus would impact other projects I develop using sbt.

Comment: I personally check the sbt launcher and sbt shell script into each project, for example: http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz. Have you just tried `System.setProperty("prop", "val")` somewhere in your project definition? Remember that SBT by default runs everything in the same process, unless you explicitly ask to to fork: http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Forking

Comment: Or in trunk, system.props("prop") = "val".  Aaaahh, that's better.

Comment: You can do that through a plugin within the shell. I wrote https://github.com/mustaghattack/jvm-command that does it.

Comment: Or, plugin free, just `sbt> eval System.setProperty("foo", "bar")`

Answer (score 8):

If I needed this option for all sbt tasks, I'd set it as follows in build.sbt

```
javaOptions += "-Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

If it was just for one task, eg: run, you can scope that:

```
javaOptions in Runtime += "-Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to set SBT properties, like plugin settings, then the following worked for me with `0.13+`. The following however did work, when trying to pass in Liquibase settings, like password, from our CI frameworks.

#### In your build.sbt

Ugly, but supplies defaults, and optionally grabs from *System.properties*. This way you've got your default and override cases covered.

```
def sysPropOrDefault(propName:String,default:String):String = Option(System.getProperty(propName)).getOrElse(default)

liquibaseUsername := sysPropOrDefault("liquibase.username","change_me")
liquibasePassword := sysPropOrDefault("liquibase.password","chuck(\)orris")
```

#### From the commandline

Now just override via `-Dprop=value` like you would with Maven or other JVM programs. Note props appear before SBT task.

`sbt -Dliquibase.password="shh" -Dliquibase.username="bob"  liquibase:liquibase-update`

Comment: "Note props appear before SBT task." good shout, this was my issue