# How to set JAVA_OPTS environment variable

Tags: java, ubuntu, environment-variables, java-opts

I have a problem while doing SSL connection through spray. I got the following error:

```
[SSLException:Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?]
```

and I found an answer [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/crowdkb/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-582877397.html).

So, how can I add the following to the JAVA_OPTS environment variable?

```
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: @Jens JAVA_OPTS is not a path, thus no `:` delimiter. It should be `set JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false"` - and even better, use `export` command instead of `set`.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3128172